# Transition Group not firing life cycle methods

Tags: reactjs, gsap

I am running some GSAP animations on a few React Component when they enter and leave the DOM.  The problem I am currently running into is that only the first component seems to be firing the enter animation. The first component does not fire the leave animation and the rest of the components do not fire any any animations.

Relevant code below

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { lastActive, activeSection } = this.state;

    let fullSection = null;
    switch(activeSection) {
      case 1:
        fullSection = <SlideOne enterFromTwo={lastActive === 2 && activeSection === 1} />
        break;

      case 2:
        fullSection = <SlideFour />
        break;

      default:
        return false;
    }

    return (
      <TransitionGroup>
        {fullSection}
      </TransitionGroup>
    )
  }
}
```

And now for Slide one

```
class SlideOne extends Component {

  componentWillEnter() {
    console.log('component will enter');
  }

  componentWillAppear(callback) {
    console.log('component will appear');

    if (!this.props.enterFromTwo) {
      this.addAnimation(this.enterAnimation, {callback: callback});
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }

  componentWillLeave(callback) {
    console.log('component will leave');
    callback();
  }

  enterAnimation({target, options}) {
    const title = target.find({name: 'title'});
    const tl = new TimelineMax({onComplete: options.callback});

    return tl.from(title, 3, {
      autoAlpha: 0,
      ease: Power2.easeIn
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <FullSection>
        <BorderedTitle name="title">connecting the music industry</BorderedTitle>
      </FullSection>
    );
  }
}
```

When Slide one is removed from the DOM the Component Will Leave lifecycle method is never called.

Does anyone have any insight into why this may be the case.

Comment: you're not running a callback on componentWillEnter , that could be it. Worth a try. Might be worth getting a jsfiddle or codepen project up so people can see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure whatever react element you want to show has a unique key, even if it's a single item.

e.g.

`<SlideOne key={ somethingUnique }/>` and `<SlideFour key={ somethingUnique }/>` -- as long as the unique keys are stable.

I apparently overlooked this when I was just concerned with the low-level API https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#low-level-api-reacttransitiongroup

React docs:

> Note:
>   You must provide the key attribute for all children of ReactCSSTransitionGroup, even when only rendering a single item. This is how React will determine which children have entered, left, or stayed.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html